# how to upgrade gcc4.1 to gcc4.7 or higher

Tags: gcc, operating-system

I have confronted a problem that the gcc version of OS(Linux) is 4.1,but now I have to use **mxnet** that needs compiler supports C++11,so I want to upgrade my gcc with higher version.
I have searched on Google,but there is only gcc4.4* to gcc4.7*,
does anyone have confronted the problem ?
give me a help.

Comment: Linux is just the kernel of your OS. What actual OS are you using? Mint, Debian, RedHat, Ubuntu, ... ? The highest GCC version in the 4.x series is 4.9, but we're actually in the GCC 6.x series by now. Since you don't need C++17 stuff, that's a bit overkill, but 4.8 or 4.9 shouldn't be hard to get.

Comment: the OS is RedHat,the gcc version is 4.1,the OS is running other program that can not be affected by my job,that is to say ,I cannot upgrade gcc4.1 in the system,but just have a gcc4.7 executed file to compile **mxnet** ,and running my program . what's more ,there are thousands of Server that have the same OS and gcc version.So it's a challenged job to upgrade all Server.

Comment: You apparently don't know that you can have more than one compiler installed? But actually that's not the real problem. You have thousands of outdated servers, that's a bigger problem than one outdated development machine. (Not a programming problem, so off-topic here, and it sounds like a management problem. I'd just dump it back on management: "server too old to run `mxnet`"